# How to check if username exists in Firebase

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

```
I have the following structure in my Firebase:

users ->
         uid ->
               provider: "facebook.com"
               username: "vandanpatel"
```

When I log the user in, I just want to check if he has his username already set or not. I have the mechanism to get the current user. I just want to check if the current user has the field "username" or not. I have tried everything, but nothing seems to work for me. if they don't have "username" field, I would make them select the "username" and set it.

Comment: Have look at this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35243492/firebase-android-make-username-unique   . You need to have proper security rules to handle this case.

Answer (score 0):

You can try:-

```
    FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("users/\(FIRAuth.auth()!.currentUser!.uid)/username").observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: {(snap) in

        if snap.exists(){

            //Your user already has a username

        }else{

            //You need to set the user's name and the the required segue

        }
    })
```

Also Check this link :- [Check if username already exists](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39612171/6297658)

Comment: I have achieved this task of uniqueness. What i am trying to do is when user tries to log in, and if his username field is already set, I would divert him to another page, so all i am trying to do is just check for my current user that if he already picked a username or not.

Comment: Answer updated, this will tell you wether or not your user already has a username stored in Firebase or not.