# Sign In by UserName : Firebase,Swift

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-authentication

I want to let user sign in with Email and also with User Name
Is that possible using Firebase ?

Comment: Yes it is, you can find these informations here in the firebase docs well explained https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/ios/password-auth and a good tutorial for showing you step by step how to do it https://www.raywenderlich.com/139322/firebase-tutorial-getting-started-2

Comment: @ronatory Thank you , but I had road these it let you sign in via Email only
,I want sign in with "User Name"

Comment: Ok then this answer might help you http://stackoverflow.com/a/35121112/5327882 . Please do a little bit more research before asking these kind of questions

Comment: @ronatory This isn't a good solution because it let user enter username and then save it as fake email for example user@appname.com 
in this solution the user can only sign in with username without his real email , and The user can't reset his password because it doesn't store in the database as real email , what I want is make him sign with "Email" and also with "User Name" , I Don't find any similar question That why I ask it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Completely separating your users account from any kind of domain specific auth credential might be a real pain later(Most definitely):-

- Updating your user password
- Privacy

A better approach is to sign up your user with an **`email-ID`** and a **`unique userName`**[Check if userName Already exists :Firebase, Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39612171/6297658), Then give your user option to *Log In* with a username or emailID.

Add another node to your JSON tree:-

```
{...

usernameEmailLink:{

    uniqueUserName1:emailID1,
    uniqueUserName2:emailID2, 
    uniqueUserName3:emailID3 

      }
 ...}
```

Update your security rules for this node:-

```
{".rules":{

 ".read" : "auth != null",
 ".write" : "auth != null",

  "usernameEmailLink" :{

    ".read" : "true",
    ".write" : "auth != null" 
     }
   }
 }
```

Code:-

```
func retrieveUserEmail(userName : String, completionBlock : ((userEmail : String) -> Void)){

    var userEmail : String!

    FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("usernameEmailLink/\(userName)").observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: {(snap) in


    userEmail = snap.value! //This will give you the email ID for the user.

     /*
       completionBlock(snap.value!)   // A even better way if this is all this function does.
     */
    })
   print(userEmail)    

}
```

For saving the key-value pair:-

```
FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("usernameEmailLink").updateChildValues["\(userName)" : "\(Email)"]
```

PS:- But before this make sure your username is unique.

Comment: How can I set both values together like "uniqueUserName1:emailID1" ?

and I got these error " Error saving rules - Line 6: Expected ',' or '}'. "

Comment: this error happened in this line   "usernameEmailLink" :{

Comment: I have updated the rules...Just copy and paste it...

Comment: Thank You very much

Comment: Last quotation how can I pass a value in snapshot ? 
what I mean I want to make Function retrieveUserEmail 
return snap.value! 
I don't know how , anything in side "})" I can't get them outside , I try to make variable outside FIRDatabase and then make snap.value! equal to it , but it doesn't work , always get nil

Comment: Hi again , sorry to bother you , but after I tried

Comment: after i tried it many time , I noticed , every time I sign up with new account it deleted the first one , always I have one line of uniqueUserName1:emailID1 , i used the same line 'FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("usernameEmailLink").setValue["\(userName)" : "\(Email)"]' , I don't know where is the problem , could you help me ?

Comment: Answer updated :)  Anyways avoid extending your queries in one question, ask a new question on SO.

Comment: Thank you very very much , That was helpful , Ok I will , Have a nice day

Comment: It should be noted that this makes users' email addresses publicly accessible.

Comment: where does the saving for the key value going ? I'm really strugling to make this work, if anybody can help me out ? it will be incredible !! here is my code if it can help . .. . https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44111403/sign-in-with-username-instead-of-email-into-ios-app-and-firebase

thanks a lot !