# Add user information with Firebase authentication.

Tags: ios, firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm implementing an Authenticate with Firebase using Password-Based Accounts on iOS.  After sign-in a user we can get particular information like `user.email`, `user.uid`, `user.photoURL`, `user.displayName`. However I can set email and password as follows.

```
[[FIRAuth auth]
     createUserWithEmail:username
     password:password
     completion:^(FIRUser *_Nullable user,
                  NSError *_Nullable error) {

     }];
```

In here no problem to get `user.email`. But I didn't set other information here. How to set other information such as `user.photoURL`, `user.displayName` with above `createUserWithEmail` method.

Answer (score 1):

You need to call FIRUserProfileChangeRequest after the user authentication to update the profile info.

```
FIRUserProfileChangeRequest *changeRequest =
    [[FIRAuth auth].currentUser profileChangeRequest];
changeRequest.displayName = userInput;
[changeRequest commitChangesWithCompletion:^(NSError *_Nullable error) {
  // ...
}];
```

Read more on https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/ios/manage-users

Answer (score 0):

You can check my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42887235/5878081). 
It can help You. But its on Swift language.

Main tip that You need to store Users in database too. And have a link to image in it.

Hope it helps